# Getting error:10054 while Connecting to local on-prem SQL server from Azure apps through hybrid connections

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-hybrid-connections

I have an Azure app that would connect to 2 local on-prem SQL Servers via hybrid connections.

- SQL Server A: OS - Windows NT 6.2; SQL Server 2016 (v13.0.4001)
- SQL Server B: OS - Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard (6.3); SQL Server 2017 (v14.0.1000)

While connecting to server B, I get error:10054 -

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

The error shows up intermittently. The success rate is around 50%. I didn't receive any error while connecting to server A.

Both hybrid connections are working well and having similar settings except the endpoint.

Both servers allow TCP and remote connections.

Is there any way to solve the error while connecting to the SQL Server from Azure?

Appreciate your support!!

***Updates***: I have checked the ECN capability, both are enabled. Something else could cause the error.

Comment: Did you ever resolve the cause of this?